# How to make UDP protocol for video streaming works on Windows 11?

Tags: udp, video-streaming, libvlc

The VLC player on Windows appears to have broken behaviour when streaming over different protocol. Here is an example:

```
CAMERA="USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam"
SIZE="640x480"

HTTP="#http{dst=localhost:8080/test.wmv}"
RTSP="#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8090/test.wmv}"
UDP="#udp{dst=localhost:8090}"

CODEC="venc=x264{preset=veryfast,tune=zerolatency,intra-refresh,sync-lookahead=0,rc-lookahead=0,keyint=25},ab=128"

TRANSCODE="#transcode{$CODEC,scale=auto,acode=none,scode=none}"

SOUT="$TRANSCODE:$HTTP"

/c/Program\ Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe -vvv \
  dshow:// :dshow-vdev="$CAMERA" :dshow-adev=none :dshow-sdev=none :dshow-size="$SIZE" \
  --sout "${SOUT}" \
  --no-audio --sout-keep
```

This could successfully set up a streaming server at "localhost:8080/test.wmv", but once I switched to UDB (according to https://docs.videolan.me/vlc-user/3.0/en/advanced/streaming/stream_over_udp.html:

```
SOUT="$UDP"
```

No video can be broadcasted, opening "udp://localhost:8090" could only yield a black screen.

How could this happen and what should be done to fix it?

**UPDATE 1:** as per requested. I now attach the VLC logs (both transmitting & receiving instances):

transmitting:

```
main debug: VLC media player - 3.0.18 Vetinari
main debug: Copyright © 1996-2022 the VideoLAN team
main debug: revision 3.0.18-0-ge9eceaed4d
main debug: configured with /builds/videolan/vlc/extras/package/win32/../../../configure '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-nls' '--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32' '--with-contrib=../contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32' '--with-breakpad=https://win.crashes.videolan.org' '--enable-qt' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-caca' 'host_alias=x86_64-w64-mingw32' 'CFLAGS= ' 'CXXFLAGS= ' 'PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/pkgconfig'
```

receiving:

```
(no debugging info at all)
```

Comment: verbose logs are missing

Comment: @mfkl they are added now

Comment: Hmm no there should be a lot more logs if you enable verbose logging from the start